# Different Views based on Logged in vs Logged out

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js

I've noticed a lot of sites, like github.com, stackoverflow.com, facebook.com all have different views based on if you're logged in or logged out (splash page vs user dynamic page)

I'm building an app off of Next JS/React, so would this be a simple if-else statement that can be done by changing the component based on if user is authenticated or not? Or is there something else that might be more complex than this?

i.e. for index.js (home page)

```
if (authenticated) {
  <SignedInView /> // this would be user feed page with bunch of dynamic content
} else {
  <SignedOutView /> // this would be a splash page
}
```

Comment: If this works for you (and I see no reason why it shouldn't) go for it! Why complicate things? Just my opinion, good luck anyway!

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I was thinking if there's like a backend or router settings that does this, or if there's any performance issues. What I was suggesting was client side, but can hackers still be able to access the component if not authenticated?

Comment: Right - the server must always guarantee that information is accessible only from the allowed users. I.e. even if `<SignedInView>` is displayed or someone accesses the endpoints that give it information directly, the server must deny access to unauthorized requests. Now, if the code is bundled in one bunch, an attacker can see the code of `<SignedInView>`. But that should NOT be a problem if the server protects the actual information. If you split code, you could even protect the code, but I do not know if it is worth the extra effort.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you for this help! Makes a lot of sense now!